# Amount of Brioche dough in a Brioche mould?

Tags: baking, bread, french-cuisine

I have a 22 cm classic fluted Brioche mold (22 cm being the widest measurement on top).  It's volume is extremely close to 1500ml. I'm wondering how much dough in total to put in it to make a "Brioche à tête".

More generalized question that would help anyone, since the tins are so varied in size:
What is the dough to mold volume ratio for making a "Brioche à tête" (e.g. grams of dough per ml of mold).

Answer (score 2):

From this [web discussion](http://www.thefreshloaf.com/node/12336/brioche-question) (very last post, at the time I read it), a poster named gcook17 shares:

> Sherry Yard's book, "The Secrets of Baking" has a table on page 233
>   with how many brioche molds of different sizes you need for 2, 2.5,
>   and 3 lbs. of dough.  She gives the mold size in inches which I take
>   to be the diameter of the top.  That assumption has worked out for me
>   so far.
>
> Here are the number of molds for 2 lbs. of lean brioche dough that she
>   gives for several sizes:
>
> 3" - 21, 3.5 - 16, 4" - 11, 5.5" - 8, 6.5" - 4, 7" - 3, 8" - 2
>
> When I use these they work fine, but I find I could probably put more
>   dough in each mold (i.e. use fewer molds) than she recommends.

It sounds like you have essentially an 8" brioche mold (and they are not exact measurements anyway), so 2 lbs or approximately 0.9 kg of dough is indicated to fill *two* such molds, so about 1 lb or 0.45 kg of dough for a single mold.